# Can your opponent counter the exert ability of Champion of Rhonas?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can your opponent counter the exert ability of [Champion of Rhonas](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426861), either as a spell or an activated ability? Does it count as a spell being cast?

Comment: Why the rollback? It is conventional in MtG to use the possessive `'s` form [even for cards whose names end in S](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22~%27s%22+o%3A%22s%27s%22). For recent examples, see the text of [Crush of Tentacles](https://scryfall.com/card/ogw/53) or [Cultivator of Blades](https://scryfall.com/card/kld/151) or [Drove of Elves](https://scryfall.com/card/c14/189).

Comment: @doppelgreener MTG templating doesn't have to affect our use of language unless we're trying to interpret templated language or use it to convey meaning. The style choice regarding the possessive was made by the asker, in clear and correct English. I think it's reasonable to change it but also reasonable for the asker to revert that particular change as they see fit.

Comment: As a caveat to that comment, I believe it's reasonable here because it's still valid English, and doesn't affect the meaning or clarity of the question at all. If people are using important game terms incorrectly, clarifying that (as edits, in comments or in answers) can help to understand the issue better. But for this case, it just doesn't matter either way. For example, should we edit all questions that say "Player A has a bear. Can they block with it?" to "Can he or she block with it?" just because that's how they template in MTG?

Comment: Ok, I'm alright with that, and didn't consider that as I made the edit. I just felt it was a weird thing to roll back. I'm fine with it staying s-less.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what went wrong with my evolutionary history for me to spend this much effort thinking about and discussing a non-issue that I'm not invested in. Then I look at the rest of the internet and I feel fine!

Comment: "Champion of Rhonas" is singular, so it should be "Champion of Rhonas's". Anyway, Changed the question to make this moot.

Comment: @ikegami Moot is a good way to go, but the singular rule isn't agreed on (like pretty much everything that comes down to style) when it comes to [proper nouns](http://apvschicago.com/2011/06/apostrophe-s-vs-apostrophe-forming.html). Moot is good. Good moot.

Comment: The most recent edit introduced a typo: "extert". I can't suggest the one-character correction edit.

Comment: @TonyUK Noting that edit summary, the "one" third-person gender-neutral pronoun is far less formal than it seems you think it is. I don't know how you've heard it used or what you read into it, but it's definitely *much* less formal than "should be reserved for the Queen", and while it *is* formal language, it gets used in [all kinds of contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)).

Comment: As a native northern British English speaker and a previous English language teacher to speakers of other languages, I would say that whilst it may be in use, it has a lot of additional cultural, class related meaning attached to it that I would not like to be associated with.

Comment: @TonyUK Ok, fair enough, it's your question. I'm a Australian and London-residing native English speaker and it has none of those particular connotations for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Champion of Rhonas's ability is a **replacement effect** followed by a **triggered ability**. You will be able to counter it during the Declare Attackers step by [effects which counter triggered abilities](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22counter%22+o%3A%22triggered+ability%22). In the current Standard format, there is one card that does this: [Disallow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDisallow%5d). (If the Exert effect has targets, you could also optionally make all of its targets illegal: this makes the rules counter the ability, and doing so is colloquially known as [fizzling](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Fizzle).) Currently this is true of all creatures with an Exert effect.

It is **not an activated ability**, and **abilities are never spells** and never count as a spell being cast. You will not be able to counter it with an effect which requires an activated ability or a spell as a target.

[Activated abilities](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Activated_ability) follow a specific format, which is (quoting the rules themselves):

> [Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]

That **`:`** following a cost (including {0}, as in [Kazuul's Toll Collector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKazuul%27s%5d%2b%5bToll%5d%2b%5bCollector%5d)) in an ability's text is the way to tell it's an activated ability. If there is no cost & colon, it's not an activated ability.

The Champion's exert ability comes in two parts as mentioned earlier: it starts as a [replacement effect](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Replacement_effect) (because of the "as"), which modifies how declaring attackers works by giving the controller the opportunity to exert it. It is followed by a [triggered ability](http://mtg.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability) that occurs if it is exerted. This triggered ability carries the "when you do..." portion of the effect, and it goes on the stack during the Declare Attackers step after attackers are declared.

All current creatures with an Exert effect work this way. [Battlefield Scavenger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBattlefield%20Scavenger%5d) and [Trueheart Twins](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTrueheart%20Twins%5d) are *slight* exceptions in that their triggered ability is a separate ability, but it will still trigger in the same way.

Comment: The official rules for Exert are already released within the [Amonkhet Release Notes](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/amonkhet-release-notes-2017-04-14), although weirdly, that section doesn't go into detail about what types of abilities and effects that keyword entails. Your interpretation, however, is backed up by the explanations below the rules paragraph.

Comment: According to those rules, Exert is simply a keyword action that means "choose to have this creature not untap during its controller's next untap step". It does not inherently involve any abilities, it is simply an action you can take. All of the existing abilities that use it only allow you to exert while declaring attackers, and additionally have a regular triggered ability that triggers when you do that.